# How are utxos associated with a particular address?

Tags: transactions, utxo

Is there a way to add or associate utxos with a particular address without creating a transaction?

Comment: There's some typo or mistake in your question that's preventing me to understand it

Comment: I corrected the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add or associate utxos with a particular address without creating a transaction?

No. UTXO stands for Unspent Transaction Output. The only operations on UTXOs are creating and spending them, and both of those operations involve a transaction.